# Supabase Bandwidth

Tags: supabase, supabase-flutter

I am new to Supabase and using a server and wanted to what does bandwidth limitation of 5gb would affect my project.

Does this limit means that all my database, storage,etc upload/download is limited to 5gb per transfer, or limited to 5gb for the entire month, and I won't be able to upload/download after I exceed this limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the latter, but we only add the outgoing traffic and not the incoming traffic. The sum of all the data you transfer out of Supabase in a month has to be within 5GB.

Comment: So basically we can send infinite data to the server but can download upto 5gb per month in the free plan?

Comment: @ShresthMittal
Infinite is a huge number, so I would use that term to be precise, but we do not charge on uploads. There are some additional thresholds for how much data you can store in the database and storage, so if you do a bunch of uploads, you will most likely hit one of those.